Instantiate a data class using the same value for multiple constructor parameters
I have a data class MyDTO that takes several parameters, but in one place where I call it, some parameters are the same. At the moment, I have a function that looks like this:
fun createDTO(f: Foo): MyDTO {
    val a = f.foo()
    val b = f.bar()
    val c = f.baz()
    return MyDTO(a, a, b, c, b, c)
}

Is there a more succinct way to do this? I especially like expression bodies, but I can't do this:
fun createDTO(f: Foo) = MyDTO(f.foo(), f.foo(), f.bar(), f.baz(), f.bar(), f.baz())

because foo, bar and baz are expensive and/or have side-effects, and therefore should only be called once.
I was thinking along the lines of:
data class MyDTO(val x1: Int, val x2: Int, val y1: Int, val y2: Int, val z1: Int, val z2: Int)

fun createDTO(f: Foo) = MyDTO(f.foo(), x2, f.bar(), f.baz(), y1, y2)

but of course I can't access the properties of MyDTO until I've finished creating the instance.


but of course I can't access the properties of MyDTO until I've finished creating the instance.

That's not true:
data class MyDTO(
    val x1: Int,
    val x2: Int = x1,
    val y1: Int,
    val y2: Int,
    val z1: Int = y1,
    val z2: Int = y2,
)

You can access any parameters declared before so you can define a default value.
Then you can have a function like this:
fun MyDTO(f: Foo) = MyDTO(
    x1 = f.foo(),
    y1 = f.bar(),
    y2 = f.baz(),
)

I renamed it to MyDTO so it is more intuitive to use. It looks like you would call a constructor (and for what matters it works the same), but actually it is just a top-level function. Such functions are therefore called constructor-like functions. This is a pattern the standard lib heavily uses as well, here for example: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/constructing-collections.html#initializer-functions-for-lists

Thanks, these are good points and therefore upvoted. But your answer has the repeated parameters in the data class definition, not at the constructor call site. It's not always the case that, for example, x2 is typically a copy of x1 in general, so I would rather do that at the call site than at the definition site.

They are default parameters. You can always pass something else if you like. Just when you don't pass anything the default values are used. You can still call MyDTO(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).
